# How do I handle events between deep-tested Vue component and its furthest parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following nested components structure:

```
<question>
    --> <answer>
        --> <best-answer-button>
    --> <answer>
        --> <best-answer-button>
    --> <answer>
        --> <best-answer-button>
```

There can be multiple questions on the page. Each question can have multiple answers.

Now, when an answer is marked as best, I need to:

- let the parent `<question>` know, to add a "best answer" label or
  take it off
- let all the sibling `<answer>`-s know

The point is, that I have to manipulate the question related to the `<best-answer-button>` and all of the question's `<answer>`-s, but I should not "touch" any other questions and answers on the page.

**Is there a smooth way to fire an event from the `<best-answer-button>` component only to its respective `<question>`?**

Comment: I'm trying to understand your app. Is it something like this? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MrrQYm?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert That's exactly it. One extra thing is when an answer is marked as "best", the respective question gets a "Best answer" label.

Comment: You can fork the pen to give an idea of what you mean there. I'm not sure I understand why a question would have a best answer label.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Answered" - that's the label name when an answer is chosen.

Comment: I updated the pen. Is that right? I'm not necessarily recommending this as the way to do it, its just one way you could.

Comment: OK, so you're basically re-emitting the event up through both parents (answer and question). I was considering it but hoped there's something cleaner I could use. The solution is valid, though, and that's what I will end up doing in the end, so thank you very much for the time spent on it.

Comment: Sure there are other ways. I'm working on an example.

Comment: Here is the idiomatic way to do it with Vuex. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/RxxQGz?editors=1010

Comment: I'm not experienced in the Vuex state management yet. May be the time to change that :)

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate of another question I answered in the past, where my accepted answer shows a kind of non Vue way to emit from a child to a grandparent. I probably would lean toward a more Vuex like approach these days. I often feel like Vuex is overkill for a small project, but I'm increasingly in the minority with that opinion :) Of course probably as a last resort you can always use an Event Bus. This is all covered in the non parent child communication section of the documentation.